# how to set raddatepicker date input box with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, raddatepicker

I am trying to set the date to "todays " date in the rad date picker but all it does is it selects it in the calendar but the box where the date is displayed is empty (i.e 12/2/2012) is not showing... Here is my line of code, (i have seen some examples in google but they are all javascript, i need to do it on the back end C#).

```
 rdpShipDate.Calendar.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
```

That line above just selecs the date in the calendar but the box is still empty.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
rdpShipDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
```